# Create Js function to make DIV and get js const text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a js function to add a dynamic DIV with some configuration.

Now I have:
HTML:

```
                  <div class="tooltip" >
                        <font class="textStyleInfo"><b>( i )</b></font>
                        <span class="tooltiptext" id="demo2">XXX</span>
                    </div>
<script>
    changeDemo("demo2",tooltiptext_controloSaldoCheckBox2);
</script>
```

JS:

```
const tooltiptext_controloSaldoCheckBox2 = "My Text";
```

With this i Can change my text but, I will use this so many times in a legacy page that i prefer to create a faster js function that i can call like this:
HTML:

```
<script> myFunction("NameDIV",tooltiptext_controloSaldoCheckBox2);</script>
```

Js:

```
function myFunction(ID_CH, Var2){
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<font class=\"textStyleInfo\"><b>( i )</b></font><span class=\"tooltiptext\" id=\""+ID_CH+"\">"+Var2+"</span>";
div.setAttribute('class', 'tooltip'); // and make sure myclass has some styles in css
document.body.appendChild(div);};
```

But when I call it i won't work :s
Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: the `<font>` tag is deprecated in HTML5, and I don't seem to understand your problem or question!

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to write all the code in the innerHTML. Better use it like this:

```
div.id = "+ID_CH+";
div.classList.add("tooltiptext");
```

The tag FONT is deprecated and shouldn't be used: https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

It's better to separately create the different tags and append them than to write them all in the innerHTML. Something like:

```
let span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = 'I love it!';
div.appendChild(span);
```

Look that your code is getting more structured, so you and other can it better understood.

Comment: And do not use `.innerHTML` if you can avoid it because it opens up security and performance issues. Use `.textContent` for non-HTML strings.